# Postgres data partitioning by date 'older than x days'

Tags: database, postgresql, partitioning

I would like to partition one of my big tables containing a lot of old data.

I thought I could partition the table by a date column.

I would like to achieve that only records from the last 30 days stay in one partition and the rest are kept in an 'archive' partition

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Thanks,
Detlef

Comment: PostgreSQL manual is pretty clear on how to use partitioning but how to do it is depening on your PostgreSQL version the more modern versions support native  partition in lower versions you need to simulate it by making more tables and using `INHERITS ` in combination with CHECK and table triggers and a function for easy inserting.

Answer (score 4):

Creating "last 30 days" and "archive" (earlier than 30 days ago) partitions that will automatically migrate the records between partitions as time passes is not a feature natively supported by Postgres even in the most recent version. You could technically do this, but you'd need scripts to migrate the data between partitions and update the partition definitions, which would quickly become unwieldy and complex, and could result in the tables being locked on a nightly basis as the partitions are updated.

Easier would be to create one partition holding all data more than 30 days ago, then create partitions for each month going forward. This is the case described in the documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html